# What am I missing when getting these errors installing Node on OSX?

Tags: node.js

Running npm install node (done successfully before on other machines) but now getting the following

npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/USERID/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/USERID/package.json'
npm WARN USERID No description
npm WARN USERID No repository field.
npm WARN USERID No README data
npm WARN USERID No license field.

Not sure what to do and searching around didn't yield results

Tried running via sudo
Tried installing from the Node website pkg
Searched around stackoverflow

Hoping to get this installed.

Comment: I am pretty sure you need to use `nvm` https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-18.04/#2-installing-node-js-and-npm

Comment: One solution is to just run `npm init` and fill in the fields. It's complaining that there's no `package.json`, which `npm` is expecting.

Comment: you use `nvm`  https://speedysense.com/install-nodejs-and-npm-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

`npm` is a package manager for Node.js, and is not itself used to install Node.js.

You will want to either:

1. Download the pkg from here and install it: https://nodejs.org/en/download/
2. Use a package manager like nvm: https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

I recommend you get the LTS version.